# Generating independent dynamic reports passing user-defined parameters in r + shiny

Tags: r, shiny, knitr, r-markdown

I would like a shiny app to offer the user the ability to download multiple versions of the same report, depending on user-defined parameters. Using the `iris` dataset as an example, the idea would be that a report would be generated for each user-defined subset of the dataset (by `Species`).

My code for the report (`test.Rmd`) is below:

````
---
title: "Parametrised report"
output: pdf_document
params:
   species: 
      label: Species
      input: select
      choices: [setosa, versicolor, virginica]
---

```{r}
df <- dplyr::filter(iris, Species %in% params$species)

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(Sepal.Length, Petal.Length)) + geom_point()
```
````

My code for the `app.R` file is below:

```
# Define the ui code
ui <- bootstrapPage(

selectInput('species', 'Select species:',
          paste(unique(iris$Species)),
          multiple = TRUE),

downloadButton('DownloadReport')

)


# Define the server code
server <- function(input, output) {

flower_species <- reactive({input$species})

observe({
lapply(flower_species(), function(i) {
  output$DownloadReport <- downloadHandler(

    filename = paste0('test_', i, '.pdf'),

    content = function(file) {

      out <- rmarkdown::render('test.Rmd', rmarkdown::pdf_document(), params = list(species = i))
      file.rename(out, file)

    }

  )
})
})

}

# Return a Shiny app object
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

The user would define the species (one or more of `setosa, versicolor, virginica`), and if several were selected, not only would the report subset the data to include just that species per report (`df <- dplyr::filter(iris, Species %in% params$species)`), but a new report would be generated for each of the selected species.

I found this link: [Shiny: dynamic UI - a loop around downloadHandler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25998680/shiny-dynamic-ui-a-loop-around-downloadhandler) which builds on this discussion: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/shiny-discuss/qGN3jeCbFRY/xOW5qoVrr94J, but this isn't quite what I need - I don't want multiple download buttons, but one download button that creates independent reports based on the inputs to `selectInput`. I was hoping the `lapply` approach shown above would work, but only one report is created. Additionally, I tried a looping approach, but that didn't work (error message was that I tried to do something reactive outside of a reactive environment).

I'm surprised not to find this anywhere - it seems like something that would be useful in many shiny apps. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: How about creating the reports in the `lapply` loop and then zipping them and passing this zip file to the `downloadHandler` ?

Comment: @Tutuchan I'm not sure I follow exactly. Would you be able to write that up as usable code? Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to get a working version but it does not work in the RStudio previewer, you have to click on the `Show in browser` button.

I think you need to remove some parts of the YAML in `test.Rmd` that are not needed here:

````
---
title: "Parametrised report"
output: pdf_document
params:
   species: setosa
---

```{r}
df <- dplyr::filter(iris, Species %in% params$species)

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(Sepal.Length, Petal.Length)) + geom_point()
```
````

app.R looks like this :

```
library(magrittr)

# Define the ui code
ui <- bootstrapPage(

  selectInput('species', 'Select species:',
              paste(unique(iris$Species)),
              multiple = TRUE),

  downloadButton('DownloadReport')

)


# Define the server code
server <- function(input, output) {

  flower_species <- reactive({input$species})

  output$DownloadReport <- downloadHandler(
    filename = "test.zip",
    content = function(file){
      files <- lapply(flower_species(), function(i) {
        rmarkdown::render('test.Rmd', rmarkdown::pdf_document(), output_file = paste0(i, ".pdf"), params = list(species = i))
      }) %>% unlist %>% basename
      zip(file, files)
      file

    }
  )
}

# Return a Shiny app object
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

It is basically the same principle that you wrote earlier but the `lapply` loop is inside the `downloadHandler content` element, and you use the `zip` function to zip all the generated reports into a single zip file that is returned. Maybe throw an `unlink` after the `zip` in order to remove all the pdfs.

Comment: That worked perfectly - many thanks for the quick solution. I wonder if it's absolutely necessary to zip the files, or if a similar method would avoid that step. Nevertheless, this works very elegantly, thanks again!

Comment: The thing is I don't know if downloadHandler can handle more than one file, hence the zip.